# Event handlers and <select> menus

Tags: javascript, select, event-handling, dom-events

I'm working with Javascript and need some help with `<select>` (aka drop-down) menus.

There will be an array of roughly 300 objects, from which the select menu will get its options.  Which elements in the array will be listed will be determined by other functions, updated as the user does things, and so the names and number of options in the select menu will not be static.  I will have the data of the currently selected object be displayed on the page.

My question is this: what type of event handler set-up (edit* listener) would I need to have the page update the data being displayed according to which option is selected in the `<select>` menu?  I'm not sure if the `.onfocus` would work for this, since I can't make an `.onfocus` event handler for an item in the `<select>` menu that may not exist at the time.  Perhaps I'm just not sure how `.onfocus` interacts with the `<select>` menu in general.  If there is some other handler than `.onfocus` that does the trick, please let me know.

```
//constructor begins
function Ingredient(params) {
    this.pic = params.pic;
    this.name = params.name;
    this.nameIsKnown = false;
    this.unrefinedPot = params.unrefinedPot;
    this.unrefinedPotIsKnown = false;
    this.refinedPot = params.refinedPot;
    this.refinedPotIsKnown = false;
    this.rawQty = 0;
    this.unrefinedQty = 0;
    this.refinedQty = 0;
    this.refineDC = params.refineDC;
    this.refineDCIsKnown = false;
    this.properties = [params.prop1, params.prop2, params.prop3, params.prop4];
    this.propertyIsKnown = [false, false, false, false];
    this.whereFound = [];
    this.isPoisonous = params.isPoisonous;
    this.genericDescription = params.genericDescription;
    this.fullDescription = params.fullDescription;
}
//constructor ends

//prototype stuff begins
//prototype stuff
//prototype stuff ends


//example object literal that gets passed to constructor
var baconParams = {pic: "bacon.png",
                    name: "Bacon",
                    unrefinedPot: 1,
                    refinedPot: 2,
                    refineDC: 17,
                    prop1: "Juicy",
                    prop2: "Crispy",
                    prop3: "Smokey",
                    prop4: "Burnt",
                    isPoisonous: false,
                    genericDescription: "Unidentified animal part.",
                    fullDescription: "This is a pig meat product that comes in strips.  It is usually fried until crispy and eaten for breakfast."};

var masterArray = [];

function fillList() {
    for (i = 0; i < masterArray.length; i++) {
        var current = masterArray[i];
        var itemName = current.name;
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.innerHTML = itemName;
        var select = document.getElementById("testselect");
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
}


var bacon = new Ingredient(baconParams);
masterArray.push(bacon);
//this is the part you gave me
document.getElementById("testselect").addEventListener("change", callback, true);

function callback(event) {
  //e.preventDefault();
  //e.stopPropagation();
  var value = event.target.value;
  var text = document.getElementById("testp");
  text.innerHTML = value;
}

fillList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a SELECT element (which you seem to be), why not use the "change" event, it'll trigger whenever a user selects an option in your menu and your event can send you event.target.value (which will be the select's value at that time) regardless of what other options are available.

If you're NOT using SELECT element, however, that's a different story.

Could you specify if you are?

**EDIT**

```
document.getElementById('yourselectelementsid').addEventListener('change', callback, true);

function callback(event) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  var value = event.target.value;

  // do stuff
}
```

All the information you'll need is in the [MDN events page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event)
Essentially, when you "addEventListener" your callback functions have an event object as a parameter, which has a "target" property, which is the element affected by the event, in this case your SELECT element.

So **event.target.value**, could also be interpreted as:
**yourSELECT.value**

Comment: I am indeed using a select element.  This is the first I've heard of the "change" listener, could you give me an example of the event.target.value it returns?

Comment: I'll post an edit to my answer, to better mark it up.

Comment: Note that if navigating options using the cursor keys, IE fires a change event each time a new option is selected whereas other browsers will only do that if it loses focus or selection is confirmed some other way.

Comment: Aye, RobG is correct. if you need to support IE, this will require additional controls.

Comment: @SebastienD.— *event.target* is the actual element that dispatched the event, which works in the case of a select and options however in most cases it would be better to use *this* to get the element that has the listener as the *eventTarget* may be a child element.

Comment: Yep, well aware of that detail. The case being a SELECT, I thought not mentioning this information would be "ok".

Comment: Thank you Sebastien and RobG, I think I've figured it out, and I got a little tester to work, however to do so I had to comment out the e. functions.  I got errors in the console log saying that e wasn't defined.  Will it be a problem if I don't include them?

Comment: Could you show your current code snippet? It would help to identify potential issues.

Comment: just change e to event.
the addEventListener method sends an "event" object to the callback function as an argument. In my case I called that object argument "event", but you could also call it "anything" and use it as:
anything.preventDefault();
anything.stopPropagation();

etc.